# Dialog input to app component causes error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting an error in angular material dialog.

I want some input from the dialog box and send it to the app's component for further processing. I checked the angular material documentation site and tried this but got some errors in console as shown below:

[image: Error can be seen here]

> ERROR: Error: No provider for MdDialog!

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import 'hammerjs';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  entryComponents:[DialogComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`dialog.component.ts`:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog:MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>, @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data:any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close(){
    this.dialog.close('close');
  }

}
```

`app.component.ts`:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private dialog: MdDialog){}

opendialog() : void{
  let dialog = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,{
    width: '500px',
    data: 'Hi How are you'
  });

  dialog.afterClosed().subscribe((result)=> console.log(result));
}

}
```

`app.component.html`:

```html
<button (click)="opendialog()">Popup</button>
```

`dialog.component.html`:

```html
<p>
  dialog works!
</p>

<button (click)="close()" md-button>Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put DialogModule in the import array of your NgModule

Comment: It's actually named `MdDialogModule`.

Comment: And now called `MatDialogModule` :)